# What studies can tell me more about Big5 facet O3?

Tags: personality

The big5 facet O3 is called "Feelings". What does this facet tell about a person's feelings exactly?

Where can I find more information on correlations to Big5 facet O3 - "Feelings"? (Im looking for links to scientific studies)